# Detect and manually set up replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

Recently we installed a new Sql Server 2008 server for a client and we had to move all the databases for them. Apparently they forgot about one application that uses replication with local Sql 2000 Desktop Edition instances. Now we're trying to get the replication running again.

Currently we get the error: The server '...' is not configured as distributor.

2 questions about that:

1. Is there a way to detect the type of replication used by just looking at the DB schema?
2. I'm guessing we don't need to run the replication wizard again since that changes the database schema which should be already ok. What do we need to do to manually hook up everything?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you made a fresh SQL Server installation, and not an upgrade, which would have been the recommended approach.

It seems that you can use both main types of replication now: merge replication and transactional replication (see [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241%28v=sql.100%29.aspx))

Since you have a fresh installation, creating the publication from scratch **is a must**. 
I recommend following the usual steps when setting up replication:

1. If at your subscriber you also need to make schema or data modifications then choose **merge replication**. If your subscribers are read-only or you don't need schema/data altered there, choose **transactional replication**.
2. Create your publication in SQL Server 2008. The distributor should also be this instance (because of replication rules between different versions of SQL Server - the distributor has to be the no earlier than the publisher). Choose your articles, snapshot agent schedule, security settings.
3. Initialize snapshot.
4. Re-create your MSDE 2000 subscription. Note that all agents should run at the Distributor.

You have to figure out your security settings. Especially how your subscribers connect to the publisher (SQL credentials or integrated security if in a domain).

So, recreating your publication shouldn't be very hard.

If you previously had merge replication setup then a real problem could be data at the subscribers that hasn't been uploaded to then publisher yet. So you have a bunch of subscribers all with their own modifications. In this situation you either discard the data or manually backup each subscriber and synchronize it after subscription initialization.